# using jquery contains inside a function?

Tags: jquery, function, variables, contains

I'm trying to use the jquery :contains (or .contains()) selector inside a function, however I can't seem to get it to work.

Basically I'm passing a string to a function and I want to check the variable if it contains X, do something else do something else. If that makes sense.

Here's my code.

```
function checkMe(myVar) {
  if ($(myVar).contains("foo")) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

and my call to the function:

```
checkMe("/foo/bar");
```

But it's not working. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery contains function checks if a dom node contains another dom node.  What you are wanting to do is just check to see if a string is contained inside another.  You could do a simple regex search for this.

Try this instead:

```
if (myVar.match("foo")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

do you have to use jquery? what about something like this?

```
function checkMe(myVar) {
  if (myVar.indexOf("foo") > -1) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi
just check the jquery api http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/ , `jquery.contains` is applied to DOM element. if you want to do string contains, try:

```
/foo/i.test("foo/bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

contains checks if one DOM element contains another.

For what you want, you don't need jQuery at all:

```
function checkMe(myVar) {
  if (myVar.indexOf("foo") >= 0) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

indexOf will return -1 if "foo" is not found in the passed string; otherwise it returns the index in the string where "foo" was found.